# comparison principle for the minimal surface equation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Consider the (inhomogeneous) minimal surface equation for functions $u,f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ for some smooth domain $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$

$$Lu:=\operatorname{div} \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}}=f.$$

Then is it true that $u_1\leq u_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus D$ and $Lu_1\geq Lu_2$ implies $u_1\leq u_2$ on $D$?

Comment: The trick for these sorts of problems is to notice that $v = u_1 - u_2$ solves a *linear* PDE. The coefficients of this PDE will depend on $u_1,u_2$, but that's no problem. If I am not mistaken the '$c$-term' should be zero, so you can just apply your normal comparison principles.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737306/maximum-principle-for-minimal-surface-equation-with-dirichlet-boundary-condition/3740035#3740035) is perhaps relevant when $D$ is bounded (and Lipschitz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case that $D$ is bounded, as Leo Moos has noted, more details can be found in a textbook of minimal surface, cf. Lemma 1.26 in T. Colding, W. Minicozzi, *A Course in Minimal Surfaces*.

That is, let $F(X)=\frac{X}{\sqrt{1+|X|^2}},$  then
\begin{equation}
F(\nabla u_1)-F(\nabla u_2)=\left(\int_0^1dF\big(\nabla u_2+t(\nabla u_1-\nabla u_2)\big) 
 dt\right)(\nabla u_1-\nabla u_2).
\end{equation}
From this, one can conclude that $v=u_1-u_2$ satisfies an equation of the form
$$\operatorname{div}(a_{i,j}\nabla v)\leq 0,$$
where the matrix is defined as $(a_{i,j})=\int_0^1dF(\nabla u_2+t(\nabla u_1-\nabla u_2)) 
 dt.$

In particular, for  a unit vector $V$ and a vector $X$, we have
$$dF(x)V=\frac{V}{\sqrt{1+|X|^2}}-\frac{\langle V,X\rangle}{(1+|X|^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}X.$$
Thus,
$$(1+|X|^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\langle V, dF(X)V\rangle=(1+|X|^2)-\langle V,X\rangle^2\geq 1, $$
which means $(a_{i,j})$ is positive,  therefore, the usual comparison principle gives the claim.